# Boot into Windows after uninstalling Ubuntu (Dual-boot)

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows

I had a Windows 7/Ubuntu dual-boot set up on my laptop. I deleted Ubuntu, and when I load up my computer, I am now met with a screen displaying the following:

```
error: no such partition. grub rescue>
```

How can I have my computer boot straight into Windows 7 again?

Solved: I created a win7 system repair disc using another machine, and fixed the problem using the `bootrec` command within command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method is to boot up with your Windows 7 disc, choose System Recovery Options and then click Startup Repair. That should generally remove grub from your master boot record and allow you to boot into Windows normally.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the windows bootloader
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 recovery, type `bootrec.exe /fixboot` and then type `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`.

Answer (score -1):

The Ubuntu partition is an extended partition. If you are in Ubuntu, C:(os) is mounted in Ubuntu with wine.

You have to boot with Windows rescue-cd and go to command prompt `cmd`. Use diskpart  more information diskpart/help

Then list disk select disk
     list partition select partition  => set c:os active

Reboot

With easeus partition master you can change extended partition into basic of logical

Install GRUB on Windows if you still have to choose between Ubuntu / Windows during startup.