# I deleted ubuntu and now I can't boot into windows!

Tags: dual-boot, windows, data-recovery

This error comes up everytime

```
failed to load image grub error efi
failed to start image
```

Then I get redirected to boot menu and every option has the same effect i.e the same error. I even tried inserting a recovery drive through usb and it resulted in the same error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsv0A.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5fNc.jpg

Comment: Did you try option `4. Windows Boot Manager`?

Comment: Not our problem :P if windows aint playing nice repair windows using windows tools

Comment: Nope but something happened. I inserted my recovery usb and then some options popped up like troubleshooting, advanced options etc. I opened cmd and did the fix mbr and stuff and still windows isn't opening up. I got back at the same options of troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes I did try windows boot manager. Same error

Comment: Looks like you deleted the Efi System Partition.

Comment: Maybe but what do i do now?

Comment: This seems to be a Windows support question. We don't support Windows here. You are asking the wrong folks for help. We support Ubuntu. Consider asking in a Windows support venue how to repair or restore or re-create your lost EFI partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do a startup repairing for windows.

you can boot your system using a windows DVD and do a startup repair.see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186250/boot-into-windows-after-uninstalling-ubuntu-dual-boot) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Issue solved! Booted from usb recoverg  drive then refresh your pc. Boom

Answer (score -1):

Try Boot Repair from Ubuntu Live session.

More info can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Hope it helps.